# Write down what metric this transformation preserves based on animation

Tags: geometry, transformation, visualization, semi-riemannian-geometry

I made this on desmos:

> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u5qpd135uc

I made it because I wanted to compare and contrast it with the [Lorentz boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

The transformation should move a point to somewhere on the same green curve depending on the parameter $b$. And the red curves get mapped to each other.

> How would I write out the transformation in concrete notation, and how would I determine the metric that this transformation preserves? (i.e. lorentz boost preserves the lorentz metric) [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space).

Maybe it doesn't preserve anything $-$ I don't know at the moment. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: Can you describe what the transformation does? I am guessing it should move a point to somewhere on the same green curve, depending on the parameter $b$? And such that the red curves get mapped to each other?

Comment: Yeah the transformation should move a point to somewhere on the same green curve depending on the parameter $b$. And the red curves get mapped to each other. I'll edit to include that

Comment: The metric preserved is $x^2-y^2$ which is met in relativity under the form $x^2-c^2t^2$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2-c^2t^2$  (see this answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564572))

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't thing this is true given the plots form geocalc33. It is another transformation.

Comment: @Milten : you are right. I have had a too quick view on the Desmos graphic.

Comment: @JeanMarie if you retract to linear coordinates, i.e. $u=\ln(x)$ and $v=\ln(t)$ it's isomorphic to the lorentz metric after re-scaling. So I think the metrics are the same in *essence*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will forget about your parameter $s$, since it just scales $b$. So points are of the form:
$$
(x,t) = \left(\exp\left({\sqrt{n}e^{b}}\right),\exp\left({\sqrt{n}e^{-b}}\right)\right)
$$
If we add a constant $\Delta b$ to $b$, we see that we can write the transformation as:
$$
(x, t)\mapsto (x',t') = \left(x^{\exp(\Delta b)}, t^{\exp(-\Delta b)}\right)
$$
This transformation maps red curves to each other and points stay on the green curves.

"The metric it preserves" is just that points stay on the green curves. These curves are given by 
$$
t=\exp\left(\frac{n}{\log x}\right)
$$
So if $(x,t)$ satisfies the above for some $n$, then also $t'=\exp\left(\frac{n}{\log x'}\right)$. The interesting thing is that $n$ is constant. We can solve for $n$:
$$
n = \log x \cdot\log t
$$
This is a preserved quantity of the transformation. I.e. you might say $\log x \log t$ is a preserved metric of $(x,t)$.

NOTE: I worked under the assumption $x>1$, $t>1$. In other regions, you may need to adjust the results.

EDIT, according to the discussion in the comments: Let
$$
(z,w) = \frac12(\log x + \log t, \log x - \log t)
$$
I.e. we take log and rotate and scale. Then 
$$
z^2 - w^2 = \log x\log t
$$
so $z^2-w^2$ is invariant. With $k=e^{\Delta b}$, the transformation becomes:
$$
(z',w') = \frac12\left((k+\tfrac1k)z + (k-\tfrac1k)w, (k-\tfrac1k)z + (k+\tfrac1k)w\right)
$$
Finally, if we substitute $1/\sqrt{1-v^2} = (k+k^{-1})/2$, we get:
$$
(z',w') = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\left(z - vw, w- v z\right)
$$
which is the Lorentz transformation with $c=1$. If we want to introduce $c$ into the original transformation, we could work backwards from here.

Comment: I feel like if you retract to linear coordinates, i.e. $u=\ln(x)$ and $v=\ln(t)$ it's isomorphic to the lorentz metric after re-scaling?

Comment: I also realise that we can just write $k:=e^{\Delta b}$. Then $(u',v')=(ku, v/k)$, and the preserved quantity is $uv$. This does indeed define a hyperbola, so I think you may be right about the connection to the lorentz metric.

Comment: We just need to rotate the $(u,v)$ system by $\pi/4$, i'd say.

Comment: To be concrete: $(z,w)=\frac12(u+v,u-v)$ preserves $z^2-w^2$. You might want to check if the tranformation on $(z,w)$ is the usual Lorents transformation.

Comment: Looks great (+1)