# What is the maximal area between hyperbola and chord $AB$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, optimization, conic-sections

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are variable points on upper branch of hyperbola $\mathcal{H}:\;x^2-y^2=-4$ such that $AB = 1$. What is the maximal area between $AB$ and $\mathcal{H}$?

[image]

Clearly $y= \sqrt{x^2+4}$. If we set $A\big(t,\sqrt{t^2+4}\big)$ then $B\big(t+h, \sqrt{(t+h)^2+4} \big)$ for some positive $h$, such that $$h^2 +\Big(\sqrt{(t+h)^2+4} -\sqrt{t^2+4} \Big)^2=1$$
and we have to find a minimum value of
$$f(t) = \int_{t}^{t+h}\sqrt{x^2+4}\;dx$$

Notice that if $$F(x):= \int\sqrt{x^2+4}\;dx$$   then $$ F(x)= 2\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2+4}+x\right|\right)+x\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{4}+1}$$
and things get complicated very quickly.

Comment: Using paretric equation look a way

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I think you mean "parametric", if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametrize the hyperbola as $x=2\sinh t $, $y= 2\cosh t$  and let the endpoints of the chord be $A(2\sinh a, 2\cosh a)$, $B(2\sinh b, 2\cosh b)$. Then, the equation of chord $AB$ is

$$y= x\tanh\frac{a+b}2 +2\frac{\cosh \frac{a-b}2}{\cosh\frac{a+b}2 }$$
and the area between the chord and hyperbola is
\begin{align}
K =&\int_{x_a}^{x_b}( y - \sqrt{x^2+4})dx\\
=&\int_a^b \left(2\tanh\frac{a+b}2 \sinh t +  
 2\frac{\cosh \frac{a-b}2}{\cosh\frac{a+b}2 }
 - 2 \cosh t  \right)2\cosh t\>dt\\
=& 2\tanh\frac{a+b}2 (\sinh^2 b -\sinh^2a)
+2\sinh(b-a)(2-\cosh (a+b) )-2(b-a)
\end{align}
Moreover, $1=AB^2=(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2 $ leads to
$$\cosh2b +\cosh 2a -2 \cos(a+b)=\frac14$$
$$\frac{d b}{da}
=\frac{\sinh2a}{\sinh(a+b)-\sinh2b}$$
Then, it is straightforward to verify that $\frac{d b}{da} = 1 $, $\frac{d K}{da} = 0 $ if $b=-a$, which leads to $\sinh b =-\sinh a=  \frac14$ and the maximum area
$$K_{max}= \frac{\sqrt{17}}4-4\sinh^{-1}\frac14$$

Comment: [+1] Therefore, the solution is with an horizontal chord.

Comment: I have improved the solution I gave some hours ago.

Comment: @JeanMarie - it is neat to consider the curvilinear triangles

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on a geometrical result  that can be seen either on the second figure [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions) or on the first figure of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3564572) of mine. It deals with the area "swept" by a moving point on a rectangular hyperbola (in close connection with the analogous second figure for circular trigonometry).

We are going to work on an equivalent problem on a rotated and scaled version of your rectangular hyperbola, with equation

$$x^2-y^2=1.$$

Its right branch is parameterizable in this way:

$$x=\cosh t, \ \ \ y=\sinh t, \ \ \ t \in (-\infty,\infty).$$

Take a look at figure 1: curvilinear triangles $OIA$ and $OIB$ have resp.  signed areas $a/2$, $b/2$. Their unsigned areas are $|a|/2$ and $|b|/2$. In the case of this figure, we have  $a>0, \ b<0$.

The area of curvilinear triangle $OB(I)A$ (red area) is

$$\dfrac12(a-b)\tag{1}$$

(proof in my answer referenced upwards).

[image]

*Fig. 1. A case where $a >0$, and $ \ b <0$ (other sign cases are possible).*

Besides, the (signed) area of triangle $OBA$ is

$$\dfrac12 \det(\vec{OB},\vec{OA})=\dfrac12 \begin{vmatrix}\cosh b&\cosh a\\\sinh b &\sinh a\end{vmatrix}=\dfrac12 \sinh(a-b),\tag{2}$$

Therefore, the area of "lunule" $IBA$ (in blue) is equal to the difference (2)-(1):

$$f(a,b):=\dfrac12 \sinh(a-b)-\dfrac12 (a-b) \tag{3}$$

Remark: formula (3) shows that the lunule's area depends only on the difference $a-b$.

Now, let us take into account condition $AB=1$ under the form :

$$g(a,b):=(\cosh a-\cosh b)^2+(\sinh a-\sinh b)^2-1=0\tag{4}$$

Let us express that we want **an extremum** of $f$ (as given by (3)) under constraint (4), by expressing it under the existence of a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $\lambda$ such that

$$\begin{cases}\lambda \ \dfrac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a} &=& \dfrac{\partial g(a,b)}{\partial a}  \\
\lambda \dfrac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b} &=& \dfrac{\partial g(a,b)}{\partial b} \end{cases}\tag{5}$$

giving:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rr}\lambda (\cosh(a-b)-1) &=& 2(\cosh a - \cosh b)\sinh a + 2(\sinh a - \sinh b) \cosh a \\
\lambda (-\cosh(a-b)+1) &=& -2(\cosh a - \cosh b)\sinh b -2(\sinh a - \sinh b) \cosh b\end{array}\right.\tag{6}$$

Adding these two equations:

$$0=2 (\cosh a - \cosh b)(\sinh a - \sinh b)\tag{7}$$

$\cosh a = \cosh b$ gives $b=\pm a$, and $\sinh a = \sinh b$ gives $a=b$.

Solution $a=b$ isn't acceptable (flat triangle!). Therefore:

$$b=-a\tag{8}$$

As a consequence, the area-maximizing chord $AB$ is **vertical**.

Now, plugging (8) into (4) gives:

$$0+(2 \sinh a)^2=1 \ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \ a=\sinh^{-1}(\tfrac14)\tag{9}$$

(of course we could have taken the opposite value for $a$).

Using (9), we deduce that the common abscissa of $A$ and $B$ is:

$$\cosh(a)=\sqrt{1+\sinh(a)^2}=\dfrac14\sqrt{17}\tag{10}$$

Using (9) in (3), the area of lunule $IBA$ is:

$$\text{area}=\dfrac12 \sinh(2a)-a = \sinh(a)\cosh(a)-a$$

$$\text{area}=\tfrac{1}{16}\sqrt{17}-\sinh^{-1}(\tfrac14)$$

which has to be multiplied by $2^2$ to find back the result of Quanto, due to the initial downscaling $2 \to 1$ operated on the hyperbola.

Comment: No comment ?....

Comment: I'm sorry, but my knowledge is poor so I can't say anything meaningfull. I hoped it is something more elementary, but... Thank you for your effort.

Comment: OK, I understand it. Maybe, in one or two years, when you come back to this answer, you will have learned the necessary concepts, in particular with Lagrange multipliers. Maybe, my answer dealing with the comparison of circular and hyperbolic trigonometry can help a little (see the improved answer).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not sure since I am still new to calculus.

---

> Find the minimum value of $f(t) = \displaystyle\int_{t}^{t + h}\sqrt{x^{2} + 4}\,dx$.

The fundamental theorem of calculus can be applied here:

\begin{align*}\dfrac{d}{dt}f(t) &= \dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{t}^{t + h}\sqrt{x^{2} + 4}\,dx \\ f'(t) &=\left(\sqrt{(t + h)^{2} + 4}\right)\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}(t + h)\right) - \left(\sqrt{t^{2} + 4}\right)\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}(t)\right) \\f'(t) &= \left(\sqrt{(t + h)^{2} + 4}\right) - \left(\sqrt{t^{2} + 4}\right)\end{align*}

Then, set $f'(t) = 0$,
\begin{align*}f'(t) &= 0 \\ \sqrt{(t + h)^{2} + 4} - \sqrt{t^{2} + 4} &= 0 \\ \sqrt{(t + h)^{2} + 4} &= \sqrt{t^{2} + 4} \\ (t + h)^{2} + 4 &=t^{2} + 4 \\ t^{2} + 2th + h^{2} + 4 &= t^{2} + 4 \\ 2th + h^{2} &= 0 \\ 2t &= -h \\ t&= -\dfrac{h}{2}\end{align*}

I don't know how to proceed now, but I hope that this can help.

---

I used the variant of the FTOC which is: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)\,dt = f(v(x))v'(x) - f(u(x))u'(x)$$

Comment: That is very helpful, actually. Plugging in $h$ in the first equation gives an equation in $t$.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but you forgot that h is a function of t

Comment: It is stated there that $h$ is a positive number, so I think I got it right, somehow.

Comment: No in next line after that there is a relation between t and h

Comment: The integral is what I tried to solve, not the relation since I don't know how to proceed there.