# What is the name for the group of hyperbolic rotations in n-dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, hermitian-matrices, hyperbolic-groups

In the case of $n = 2$, a hyperbolic rotation matrix by an arbitrary angle looks like:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cosh(\theta) & \sinh(\theta)\\ 
 \sinh(\theta) & \cosh(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$

$\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}^{1}$

These are Hermitian matrices with real entries. So is there a specific name/symbol for the n-dimensional real Hermitian matrix group? These are the hyperbolic equivalent of the SO(n) groups.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the matrices you've written referred to as "[hyperbolic rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2668264/26369)", and they/related matrices appear in discussions of the [Lorentz group(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group), like the [Wikipedia entry for "rapidity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity).

In higher dimensions, I am not sure if the Lorentz group is what you're looking for, though.