# any physical interpretation for these two matrices?

Tags: matrices, rotations

I know that the physical interpretation of $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$ is the rotation matrix.

But what are the physical interpretations of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\ -\cos\theta & \sin \theta \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} \sec \theta & \tan \theta \\ \tan\theta & \sec \theta \end{pmatrix}$ ?

I have tried with a couple of values but was unable to arrive at a conclusion.

Comment: Second matrix represents [hyperbolic rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668264/is-hyperbolic-rotation-really-a-rotation).

Comment: i can't see the resemblance. in your post, hyperbolic rotation is made up of hyperbolic cos and sin, i can't seem to find a way to express them in terms of secant and tangent.

Comment: Notice that both satisfy $X^2-Y^2=1$ or in the answer below, the diagonal entries satisfy $XY=1$, equations for a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\ -\cos\theta & \sin \theta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & -\sin \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\ \sin \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & \cos \left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \end{pmatrix}$$

So it is also a rotation matrix.

A physical interpretation for the other is not so clear to me. But the diagonalization may help.

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sec \theta & \tan \theta \\ \tan\theta & \sec \theta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \sec \theta - \tan \theta & 0  \\ 0  & \sec \theta + \tan \theta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: nice, i didnt notice the phase-shifted sine/cosine. thanks.